# What are the basics to slowly becoming a runner?

Tags: running, beginners

i always say i not a runner, I'm a swimmer! i really am not much of a runner and used to be a competitive swimmer and thinking maybe it is time to slowly get into running. How do i get into running without over doing it?

Comment: *Running With Lydiard* book is really good starting point! See more detailed answer [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/32484/15890).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best advice I have is to set a goal to compete in some type of a race a few months from now. You can then leverage training programs such as Couch 2 5k in order to set a plan to reach that race goal. From there you can decide if you want to increase your distance or decrease your time and find a new plan to meet that goal as well.

Here are a few resources for creating run training plans:
Couch 2 5k,
Endomondo,
Training Peaks,
Runners World

If you decide not to use a predefined plan, then I would suggest starting out by running/jogging a couple kilometers per day and slowly increase your mileage. By slowly, I mean less than a 10% increase per week.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips i heard the couch 2 5k was a good app to use so i downloaded that one! i had done a 5k a while back probably last November and i could tell i am out of shape.i slowly want to ease into running.